# Show the first element in a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist

I have a JComboBox with a list of elements. So what the program basically does is user select an element from the combo list and click a button to display the selected element in the text area.

Everything works perfect so far, but the problem is after user click the button I want the combo box to return back to the firs element and display the first element. How can I display the first element of the combo box...????

Comment: What program? Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [`JComboBox#setSelectedIndex(0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29).

Answer (score 2):

[JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) implements two methods for set Item

```
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(int);

comboBox.setSelectedItem(Object);
```

more in the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327352/how-to-set-selected-index-jcombobox-by-value/8327465#8327465)

Comment: It's actually [`setSelectedItem(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 2):

In the action listener you have to reset the selectedIndex of the comboBox to the first position after you have updated the text area with the selected value.

Sample code :

```
package com.mumz.test.swing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


public class JComboBoxTest {
    private void init(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        Object[] values = new String[]{"One","Two","Three"};
        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(values);
        panel.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(2, 2);
        panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton button = new JButton("Action");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.setText((String) comboBox.getSelectedItem()) ;
                comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
        });
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JComboBoxTest().init();
    }
}
```